# Hyponormal operator and approximate spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space.

It is well known that if $T:H \to H$ is a normal operator, then
$$\sigma(T)=\sigma_{ap}(T),$$

where $\sigma_{ap}(T)$ is defined as: $\lambda \in\sigma_{ap}(T)$ iff there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ with $\Vert x_n \Vert = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \Vert Tx_n - \lambda x_n \Vert = 0,$$

> If $T$ is hyponormal i.e. $T^*T\geq TT^*$, is 
>   $$\sigma(T)=\sigma_{ap}(T)?$$

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As usual, the counterexample is the unilateral shift $S$. We have $\sigma_{ap}(S)=\mathbb T$, while $\sigma(S)=\overline{\mathbb D}$.

Comment: Please what is $\mathbb T$?

Comment: The unit circle (the "one-dimensional torus").